# Python multiline pattern search

Tags: python, multiline, python-re

I've got the below text which I need to parse to extract all groups of three values. For this specific example I need an output like this: [1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,2,3],[4,2,4]
I was trying to use this reg expr:

```
re.findall(r'measId \d+,[\n\r]measObjectId \d+[\n\r],reportConfigId \d+',output)
```

but it always returns zero result. I've tried multiple combinations with re.MULTILINE flag and without the one but it makes no difference.
What am I doing wrong? any advice?

```
measIdToAddModList {
          {
            measId 1,
            measObjectId 1,
            reportConfigId 1
          },
          {
            measId 2,
            measObjectId 2,
            reportConfigId 2
          },
          {
            measId 3,
            measObjectId 2,
            reportConfigId 3
          },
          {
            measId 4,
            measObjectId 2,
            reportConfigId 4
          }
```

Comment: There are many spaces between a line break and a word on the next line. Your pattern does not match them.

Comment: Instead of `[\n\r]`, use `\s*`

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. \s* didn't really make any difference. Still 0 matches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the most naive solution. It works only if exactly three fields are present:

```
re.findall(r'\{\s+(\w+\s+\d+),\s+(\w+\s+\d+),\s+(\w+\s+\d+)\s+}', s)
#[('measId 1', 'measObjectId 1', 'reportConfigId 1'), 
# ('measId 2', 'measObjectId 2', 'reportConfigId 2'), 
# ('measId 3', 'measObjectId 2', 'reportConfigId 3'), 
# ('measId 4', 'measObjectId 2', 'reportConfigId 4')]
```

Explanation:

```
\{          # Opening curly brace 
\s+         # One or more spaces
(\w+\s+\d+) # word, spaces, digits
,\s+        # comma, spaces
(\w+\s+\d+)
,\s+
(\w+\s+\d+)
\s+         # spaces
}           # Closing curly brace
```

Comment: thanks a lot! It does work. As a bonus, do you think you can explain in English what this pattern does?

Comment: I added an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern `[\w]+\s[\d]` matches a line with what you need.

Use python for get everything you need. Suppose you have the input as a `str` named `input`.

```py
import re
from collections import defaultdict

output = defaultdict(list)

pattern = re.compile(r'(?P<key>[\w]+)\s(?P<value>[\d])')
for line in input.splitlines():
  match = pattern.search(line)
  if match:
    key = match.group('key')
    value = match.group('value')
    output[key].append(value)
```

`output` is then a dictionary, where keys are the text values and the values are lists with the numbers to the right of the text.

```
{'measId': ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
 'measObjectId': ['1', '2', '2', '2'],
 'reportConfigId': ['1', '2', '3', '4']}
```

Not sure about the output you need, but definitly possible to model it from there. For example:

```py
>>> list(zip(*output.values()))
[('1', '1', '1'), ('2', '2', '2'), ('3', '2', '3'), ('4', '2', '4')]
```

Check it out in [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1jvJYcrSNox17PJXCggeDCAg0cvl4hmoK?usp=sharing)